How to work with multiple react quill editors on the same page
I'm quite new to using React, and React Quill. I'm trying to get the user to type into 4 different quill editors and then use getText() and getContent() on the 4 editors. However, I don't know how to specify which editors to pull from. I've given each editor a ref (editor1, editor2, editor3, editor4). Then when I try to pull the content from each editor I will get "getText() is not a function" or "getContents() is not a function"
Thank you in advance. I appreciate any help.
const editor1 = useRef(null);
  const editor2 = useRef(null);
  const editor3 = useRef(null);
  const editor4 = useRef(null);

    const handleSave = async (
        e,
        content,
        delta,
        source,
        
      ) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
          const { data, error } = await supabase.from("Notes").upsert([
            {
              id: getId(),
              title: editor1.getText(),
              s1_delta: editor1.getContents(),
              s2_delta: editor2.getContents(),
              s3_delta: editor3.getContents(),
              s4_delta: editor4.getContents(),
            },
          ]);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };

    /different section of code in the same file/

    <div className={s.container}>
        <div className={s.quadrant1}>
          <ReactQuill
            modules={modules}
            theme="snow"
            ref={editor1}
            name="title"
            className={s.editor1}
            placeholder="Title"
          />
        </div>

I tried changing the ID name and searching everywhere but found nothing.

Please do not post (or link) images of code or text as they can be blocked by corporate proxies, certain school networks, and entire countries, images cannot be interpreted by screen readers, making them completely inaccessible for users with visual impairments, code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem, and images can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers or even present readers using Ctrl + F.
